# Flutter local notification sometimes doesn't work in the release version of the app

Tags: android, flutter, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

I'm using flutter_local_notification periodicallyShow() method. but sometimes it doesn't show the notification, sometimes it does, just in the release version! While in the debug mode, it works fine! (running on the device as an emulator)

I tried all of these:

1. flutter build apk --no-shrink
2. add keep.xml file to my android/app/src/main/res directory
3. edit AndroidManifest.xml based on [this](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) (add permission, etc.).

also, I want to try these options (later):

[this](https://medium.com/geekculture/push-notification-in-flutter-in-background-as-well-as-foreground-using-firebase-1e6e7ecad292) example.

and using proguard-rules.pro file like [this](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/master/flutter_local_notifications/example/android/app/proguard-rules.pro).

What should I do?!

Is there any solution?!

Thank you.

code snippet:

```
final AndroidNotificationDetails _androidNotificationDetails =
      const AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'channel ID',
    'channel name',
    playSound: true,
    priority: Priority.max,
    importance: Importance.max,
  );
Future<void> scheduleNotifications() async {    
await FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().periodicallyShow(
      1,
      "title",
      "body",
      RepeatInterval.everyMinute,
      NotificationDetails(android: _androidNotificationDetails),
      androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
    );
}
```

(if it helps: one time, when I plugged my phone into the charger adapter, it worked perfectly. and then I unplugged my phone, after that its timing became messy!!!)

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Will look into it later tonight. Good luck! If u find the solution, pls, post it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @HaKim , I migrated to awesome_notification package that hasn't the problem. but I have another one: scheduled notification stops after device reboot(/boot)!

Comment: Thanks for response. My notificiations started working flawlessly after I moved methods to the same class they were called. Before I had them in a different class.

Comment: @HaKim can you give an example of what you mean. Its not clear what "I moved methods to the same class they were called" means.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser did you ever solve this?

Comment: I had the same behaviour when I wanted to show periodic notifications after a FCM notification. It seemed like my background handler wasn't being called in release mode. I added @pragma('vm:entry-point') above the method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74599764/notification-is-not-coming-in-release-mode-when-flutter-app-is-in-background

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too. My solution was to use flutter create name_of_project again, and after creating another project, i copied all the files from the old project to the folder of my new project. Inside my pubspec.yaml, i updated the firebase_messaging from the ^11.3.0 and local_notifications from ^9.4.0 to those versions below:

````
 flutter:
   sdk: flutter
.
   cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
   firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
   flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0```
 
 Don't forget to put:
 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in your android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml. 

 After all, you just need to run: 
   
   > flutter build apk --split-per-abi --no-shrink  
   or 
   > flutter build apk --no-shrink
````